# onViewCreated called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have one activity and fragment inside, I open second activity for result from my fragment :

```
startActivityForResult(LocationSelectorActivity.newIntent(context!!), START_LOCATION_SELECTOR)
```

If i force activity for die when user will leave it ( from developer option) , after back click from my second activity onViewCreated is called twice in my fragmetn

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

Here is how I add fragment :

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        addFragment(MyFragment(), R.id.content_frame)
    }


fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int) {
    supportFragmentManager.inTransaction { add(frameId, fragment) }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm correctly following what you're saying, but are they separate instances? You're unconditionally adding a `Fragment` there without checking if one already exists.

Comment: actually I do, because it should be called only once for this activity

Comment: If that's your actual code, then a new `Fragment` instance is added each time `onCreate()` runs. If the first `Activity` is being destroyed when you go to the second `Activity`, then the first `Activity` is being recreated when you go back, so `onCreate()` runs again, but the first `Fragment` instance is still attached to the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: AddFragment should only be called if saved instance state is null

Comment: I would recommend just checking with the `FragmentManager` if the `Fragment` already exists. I realize that even Google's examples show that, but checking if `savedInstanceState` is null isn't a great solution, IMO, especially if you're going to end up juggling multiple `Fragment`s. It's best just to get in the habit of directly checking with `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score -2):

The problem rises in following line:

```
startActivityForResult(LocationSelectorActivity.newIntent(context!!), START_LOCATION_SELECTOR)
```

LocationSelectorActivity.newIntent(context) must be replaced by:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(/*your desirable configiration*/);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, START_LOCATION_SELECTOR);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(/*your desirable configiration*/);
startActivityForResult(intent, START_LOCATION_SELECTOR);
```

then in your host activity or the fragment override `onActivityResult()` method